# Sliding tabs - NullPointerException - Toolbar.getTitle()

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to implement tabs in my application. The issue is with Toolbar being null. I am following this tutorial: http://android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

The error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.getTitle()' on a null object reference`

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <com.android4devs.slidingtab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //error
```

tool_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: did you call setContentView ?

Comment: setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //error Is this where you are getting error?. because the error is a NullPointerException on getTitle()

Comment: can you post the activity code as well atleast onCreate part

Comment: also do you have layouts in different layout folders by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error was because I forgot to go back to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try, but i think removing the `android:id="@+id/tool_bar"` from the include tag and adding it to the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar tag will solve the problem.